# MSSQL syntax error getting stucked

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, row-number

I want to fetch records by some specific message id with some fixed number of records
, I am trying with the following but can't understand how to make the query work.
Can anyone please help me from this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM    ( SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) as row 
          FROM (select * from message where messageid=26) as id 
          WHERE  row > 121 and row <= 131 ;
```

I know I didn't close the first opening bracket because I simply don't know the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
 SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) as row 
 FROM (select * from message where messageid=26) as id
) as cte
WHERE  row > 121 and row <= 131 ;
```

You need to provide an alias for each subquery you use. That means you need one for the inner select statement , and one for the middle select statement.